# Loop through mysql query with PHP Prepared Statement and order by int

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have this piece of code:

```
$item_number = 0;
$rowsize = 12;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsize; $i++) {

        $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare('SELECT z, name FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE house_room1.ref_id = ? ORDER BY z'); 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $i
        );
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($z, $name);
                while($stmt->fetch()) {
                   echo '<li id="item-' . $item_number . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $name . '</li>';
                        }
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Something went terribly wrong' . $mysqli->error;
                        }
                $stmt->close();
                //$n++;
                $item_number++;
            }
```

which loops through a query 12 times (currently 12, will be higher) and select a name and a z value from a specific ref_id. Since this loop goes through 12 times, I get the z value from all the 12 ref_id's. The problem is that I can't order the query I get out because of the fact that it only takes out one query at a time. Uhm I need it to get the z value of all 12 (and soon more) and still be able to order the output by the z value. Preferably by only looping through the query once. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
$item_number = 0;

    $i = 12;

    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare('SELECT z, name
    FROM house_room1
    INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id
    WHERE house_room1.ref_id < ?
    ORDER BY z'); 
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $i
    );
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($z, $name);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<li id="item-' . $item_number . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $name . '</li>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Something went terribly wrong' . $mysqli->error;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $item_number++;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are limiting to specific ref id's?  could you include your table columns? Also, could you edit your question with the indenting a little less severe?

Comment: I tried with the indent lol idc what happened, uhh I'll fix that in a sec, The ref_id's are not limited and can increase through time.

Comment: Any time you have a query inside a loop, something's gone "terribly wrong"

Comment: @Strawberry explain yourself please, is it ineffecient, bad practice or?

Comment: It's horribly inefficient, and thereby bad practice. As a general rule, you want to make as few round trips to the database as possible!

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for notifying me about this, I thought about it but heard from another source that since I have already got connection to the database, it doesn't matter how many queries I make. Well, I'll stick to my instincts and your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the results in an array and then ordering the array:

```
$item_number = 0;
$rowsize = 12;

$itemArray = array();
$finalArray = array();
$results = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsize; $i++) {

        $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
        $stmt->prepare('SELECT z, name FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE house_room1.ref_id = ? ORDER BY z'); 
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $i
        );
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($z, $name);
                while($stmt->fetch()) {


               $results = 1;
               $itemArray['number'] = $item_number;
               $itemArray['name'] = $name;
               $itemArray['ref_id'] = $z;
               array_push($finalArray, $itemArray);

                        }
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Something went terribly wrong' . $mysqli->error;
                        }
                $stmt->close();
                //$n++;
                $item_number++;
            }

if($results == 1){
aasort($finalArray,"ref_id");

foreach($finalArray as $arr){
echo '<li id="item-' . $arr['number'] . '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $arr['name'] . '</li>';
}

}

//create a function for sorting
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
```

So basically what I added to your code, is the two array variables:
**itemArray** = is the array you we are creating with the results
**finalArray** = is the array we push all the itemArrays onto. This was you are creating a multidimensional array which we can later sort.

Then we set the variable **$results**, this is going to make sure that the results were found otherwise we will not run the code.

**function aasort** does what you want, sorts the information accorrding to the array tag (in this case ref_id)

Then you simply loop through the now ordered results and output. Very simple and should be fast. I do recommend not looping through sql queries though. You should try to have as few queries as you can to the database. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: uhm, this might be interesting to me, since I need the values somehow to connect to a jquery sortable function uhmm which I haven't provided in this question since I didn't know it was important

Comment: if you want, we can go to chat and I can provide you with the neccesary code? Uhm if that's possible, thanks

Comment: to do that you could add a simple order id to the li element and sort it with jquery. You could actually sort the entire list with jquery if needed.

Comment: yeah I have never used chat on here, but sure.

Comment: Okay, it normally comes up asking if we want to start a chat if we have chatted too much on here. Lol

Comment: I don't know any other way to do it, well it might come up in a little while

Comment: Maybe if I write one more sentence here, it will come up

Comment: Well I also have another query to look on actually

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49102/discussion-between-owwyess-and-liveandream)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to write one query and let the server sort it? Something like this...

```
SELECT z, name
FROM house_room1
    INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id
WHERE house_room1.ref_id < ?
ORDER BY z
```

This has the benefit of being one query, rather than 12 (and therefore more efficient) and it allows you to order the **WHOLE** result set any way you please.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but what do I do with the for loop now? I have gotten a little confused

Comment: loop through the results to echo them.

Comment: When you loop through the results with
    while($stmt->fetch()) {}
you'll get all the same info that you have now.

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest Well I guess I use the while loop for that, right? Thanks btw

Comment: @Kryten I have added an update above, does it look like you espect? It does it right now I guess, I just got other problems uhm, which is a whole other subject than what this question is about, maybe it's still something to do with my code?

Comment: Looks like it ought to work. Sorry, I'm not in a position to try it out right now.

Comment: while loop would be great.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with some other code I have, thanks for help, this basically did what I needed.